# Use nested variable within a function

Tags: r, tidyverse

How do I make the last line work? I am just trying to use the data within the nested tibble in the function.

```
require(tidyverse)

# Make some data
df <- data.frame(Unit = sample(1:20, replace = T, size = 100))

df$n = rpois(n = nrow(df),lambda = 200)

# Nest n
df <- df %>% nest(y = n)

# Make another var
df$x <- rnorm(n = nrow(df), mean = 100,sd = 6)

# make some function
some_function <- function(n,x){
  mean(n) * x
}

# Make a new variable Z using the n and x
df %>% mutate(z = some_function(y$n,x))
```

Answer (score 2):

We may need to loop over the `list` of `tibble` with `map2` and then apply the `some_function` over each individual list elements

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(z = map2_dbl(x, y, ~ some_function(.y$n, .x)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 4
    Unit y                    x      z
   <int> <list>           <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     6 <tibble [5 × 1]> 103.  21688.
 2     5 <tibble [3 × 1]> 101.  21126.
 3     3 <tibble [8 × 1]>  97.5 19494.
 4    18 <tibble [8 × 1]> 106.  21085.
 5    14 <tibble [7 × 1]> 102.  19958.
 6     9 <tibble [4 × 1]> 110.  22008.
 7    13 <tibble [6 × 1]> 101.  19278.
 8    20 <tibble [6 × 1]> 109.  21729.
 9     8 <tibble [5 × 1]> 103.  19031.
10     2 <tibble [4 × 1]>  96.2 19463.
11    19 <tibble [3 × 1]>  91.2 17238.
12     4 <tibble [6 × 1]>  91.9 17716.
13    11 <tibble [6 × 1]> 109.  21803.
14     7 <tibble [4 × 1]>  97.7 20371.
15    16 <tibble [5 × 1]> 100.  20941.
16    12 <tibble [6 × 1]>  94.4 19690.
17    15 <tibble [4 × 1]> 110.  22195.
18     1 <tibble [6 × 1]> 104.  19182.
19    10 <tibble [2 × 1]>  96.5 21480.
20    17 <tibble [2 × 1]>  96.0 19833.
```

Comment: The simplicity of the answer makes it so impressive

Comment: Okay, now that is exactly what I need!